# Unix: Copy all words in a file that contains the word "Justin" to another file

Tags: files, grep

I have a text file containing all the usernames in a website. I am trying to copy all words in that file containing the word "Justin" (for example, "JustinLee1", "JustinWang04") to another file. Is there a command (more specifically, a `grep` command) that would  enable me to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you care about case?  ie would `justinlee1` also count?  Does the file contain one username per line or would they be embedded in other data?

Comment: @Jesse_b I don't care about case and the file contains one username per line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with:

```
grep -i 'justin' input.txt > output.txt
```

`-i` tells grep to ignore case, any combination of `[Jj][Uu][Ss][Tt][Ii][Nn]` will be matched and put into the `output.txt` file